# Extração de arquivo zip

Tags: vb.net

Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Quando chega no algoritmo pra extrair o arquivo .zip do local o programa para de responder. Estou usando como referência a dll Ionic.zip

```
Private Sub Descompactar()
    Using zip As ZipFile = ZipFile.Read(dirlocal & "\macro.zip")
        For Each entry As ZipEntry In zip
            entry.Extract(dirlocal, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
        Next
    End Using

    On Error Resume Next
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(dirlocal & "\macro.zip")
    MsgBox("teste.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="teste")
    Process.Start(dirlocal & "/programa.exe")
End Sub
```

Comment: Já tentou depurar? Por que não usa a biblioteca ZIP nativa?

Comment: No fim eu mudei o código de extração mas não era ele e sim o de download que errei um código e o arquivo vinha corrompido. Esse algoritmo está certo também, só deu problema porque o arquivo vinha corrompido devido ao algoritmo de download